# How to identify a specific operating system with port scans?

Tags: operating-systems, network-scanners, identification

According to the implementation of the TCP/IP stack an attacker is able to identify which operating system is running on a network device. Is there any paper or the like according on this topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also a Nessus Plugin for that. You can find more details [here](http://www.tenable.com/blog/enhanced-operating-system-identification-with-nessus).

By the way, this technique is called **OS Fingerprinting**. You can find more details about it on this [Wikipedia Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP/IP_stack_fingerprinting) of course and in [this SANS paper](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/testing/overview-remote-operating-system-fingerprinting-1231).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [Remote OS Detection](http://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html) would be of interest to you.  And, of course, you can test what you see there with nmap.